# Vimeo Video Embed Field with Colorbox Formatter not opening up after update to 8.9.3

Tags: 8, views

I was running Drupal 8.8.2. I created a view which pulled the video embed field from a custom content type, formatted it as a colorbox, and opened up the video when clicked on.

After the update to Drupal 8.9.3, clicking on the video no longer opens up a colorbox (it doesn't do anything).

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you update the contrib modules as well?

Comment: Any console errors?